# Why is an unsigned int regarded as a long? Am I missing something?

Tags: c#

Is `UInt32`, `UInt64`, or `uint` really a `long`? I thought the only difference between an `unsigned int` and an `int` is that `unsigned` integers are not marked to allow for negative numbers, and that they can only contain positive numbers, right?

If that's so, then why is Visual Studio telling me that:

```
this.SomeProperty = this.Width - BorderThickness;
```

cannot be converted from type `long` to type `int`?

I'm currently using:

```
uint BorderThickness;
```

however, as usual, if I change it back to:

`int BorderThickness;` it will work.

Why is an `unsigned` `int` a `long`? Why not just call it a `long`?

Comment: if you do math on an `uint` and `int` it probably converts to `long` to not lose precision because a `uint` has a higher max value than an `int`.

Comment: A UInt32 can't be implicitly converted to Int32 (since it's lossy, and losst implicit conversions aren't a good idea) and the opposite direction isn't possible either. So C# extends to a type containing both, Int64 when you do an operation involving both.

Comment: @DLeh would you recommend that I simple cast to `int`: `(int)BorderThickness;` or just use a plain old `int` and handle any cases where it may be negative?

Comment: if you're not going to go above the int max value, (which you probably won't) casting to `int` is fine

Comment: @Jase I recommend using an `int`. In general unsigned types are a pain in C# and should only be used where necessary. Throw an exception in the property setter if the new value is invalid.

Comment: @jase, or use a ushort, I'm guessing BorderThickness doesn't get very large

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Addition of int and uint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26368068/addition-of-int-and-uint)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your question is based on a misunderstanding.

When you add, subtract, multiply, etc, an `int` and a `uint`, C# automatically promotes both to `long`, and therefore the result is `long`.

C# defines operators

```
int + int --> int
long + long --> long
uint + uint --> uint
ulong + ulong --> ulong
```

and so on.  Which of those is the best choice when given the bizarre expression `int + uint`?  It cannot be `int + int` because the `uint` might not fit; a uint could be 3000000000 which is too big for an int.  It can't be `uint + uint` or `ulong + ulong` because the int might be negative. The best choice is `long + long`, so the result is a long.

You have discovered the correct solution: **do not use `uint` in the first place**.  There is almost never a good reason to use `uint` in C#. If your quantity can have a value larger than the largest value in an `int`, then use a `long`. Unsigned integers are in C# primarily for interoperability with other languages that support them; write your business logic using signed integers.