# Mixing signed and unsigned in C#

Tags: c#

In C and C++ mixing signed and unsigned types in expressions can be tricky since here

```
void foo(void)
{
 unsigned int a = 6;
 int b = -20;
 (a+b > 6) ? puts("> 6") : puts("<= 6");
}
```

output could (unexpectedly) be `">6"` due to promotions. `b` will be promoted to unsigned.
Do same things happen in C#? **Is it also dangerous to mix signed and unsigned in C# expressions?**

Comment: did you try it? `uint a = 6;
int b = -20;
Console.WriteLine(a + b > 6 ? ">6" : "<6");`

Comment: @DLeh: Even if I try that doesn't give me general answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26368068/addition-of-int-and-uint

Comment: it's dangerous if you don't take possible issues into account. try `Console.WriteLine(typeof(a+b));` That will tell you the type of the result.

Comment: @Gread.And.Powerful.Oz that will rather get you a syntax error :)

Comment: @DLeh: So in C# you don't get surprises because of such operations? that answer answers just one case

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski:So in C# you don't get surprises because of such operations? that answer answers just one case

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski and what syntax error would you expect to get? It's an object and WriteLine takes an object and will call ToString() on it.

Comment: @Gread.And.Powerful.Oz `typeof` expects a type name

Comment: You can also `(a+b).GetType()`

Comment: @BenVoigt: Can I get unexpected results by mixing these types?

Comment: @DLeh: Actually that what you marked duplicate doesn't answer the question in the way I stated!

Comment: @Quser nothing is "unexpected" since every type promotion is well-defined in C#. When in doubt, simply use `var` (this is the equivalent of C++'s `auto`)

Comment: @Quser: I don't recall the C# type-handling rule offhand.  Type promotions are covered in the language spec.  `((int)(a+b))` should be safe.

Comment: @quser from the answer in the other thread: `The other implicit numeric conversions never lose any information. `, so you will be safe doing this.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: In C++ you can see the result is clearly unexpected, so I was wondering how in C#? I have feeling this is not duplicate of the question linked

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski gaaah!

Comment: @Quser actually I'm pretty sure type promotion is well-defined in C++ too, but not necessarily to the same types as in C#. Most of C# code in the wild doesn't bother to use unsigned types, and just default to `int`, even when the value should intrinsically be unsigned.

Comment: C++ can bring and make more surprises in such situations than C#

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: It is well defined but if you don't know promotion rules would you expect ">6" in my example?

Comment: @DLeh: I don't think this is exact dupe because this question could have a more general answer but you closed it

Comment: @Quser my stance on this is that you should know the language you're using, no excuses :-) In C++ I'd expect at least a compiler warning for this,  and for me getting a warning means the code is broken. The duplicate question's answers contain relevant spec citations, and there's no more general answer than the detailed spec.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: "In C++ I'd expect at least a compiler warning for this, and for me getting a warning means the code is broken" - I don't think you will necessarily get warning, depends on compiler maybe

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: Then I meant more digestable answer

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: I'd advise to vote to reopen

Comment: @DLeh: I'd advise to vote to reopen, maybe this one attracts more digestable answers

Comment: @Quser i will vote how i choose to vote, thank you very much. And I think that your bolded question "is it dangerous" is easily answered by the quote I mentioned before which specifically says that it is always safe.

Comment: @Quser that's not going to happen - your question is the textbook definition of a duplicate, and the answers in the other question are very good and complete. There's no need to duplicate that information here.