# Multiplying int and uint results in long?

Tags: c#

Today I learned that the following code is illegal since res2 ends up being a long.

```
        public void test(int intVal1, int intVal2, uint uintVal)
        {
            int res1 = intVal1 * intVal2;
            int res2 = intVal1 * uintVal;
        }
```

See below screenshot that shows that `long.operator *` is used for the multiplication, presumably because uint has a larger range of positive values than int can represent. It kind of makes sense but multiplications of two signed integers can also easily overflow so why the extra toughness for uint?

[image]

I've been programming C# since its inception so I'm surprised to just run into that now. Is there a good reason for promoting to long when there's a uint involved but not for two ints?

Comment: I think it has something to do with how the overflow is handled in both the cases. when we are dealing with ints the overflow will change the last bit to make it negative number, but when we are dealing with uint, there is no such possibility so it has to use higher type? any more ideas?

Comment: The "direct reason" is given by [12.4.7 Numeric promotions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#1247-numeric-promotions) but no motivation is included. `operator *(int, uint)` could trivially have been defined, but wasn't. As you say, `int * int` can also overflow very easily.

Comment: @Naruto it's not quite like that, rather you get the lowest 32 bits of the "full" product. Sometimes that means the sign changes, sometimes not. For example `int a = 65536; Console.WriteLine(a * a);` prints zero, the product overflowed but the sign didn't change. The product of an `int` with a `uint` could return the lowest 32 bits of the product as well (that's not what it does, but it could have been defined that way).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Addition of int and uint](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26368068/11683)

Comment: @GSerg thanks that adds another interesting wrinkle about operator+ I didn't even know about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's due to numeric types promotion. From [ECMA-334:2023](https://ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-334/) C# standard:

> **12.4.7.3 Binary numeric promotions**
>
> Binary numeric promotion occurs for the operands of the predefined +, –, *****, /,... Binary numeric promotion implicitly converts both operands to a common type
> which, in case of the non-relational operators, also becomes the result type of the operation. Binary
> numeric promotion consists of applying the following rules, in the order they appear here:
>
> • If either operand is of type decimal...
>
> ...
>
> • Otherwise, if either operand is of type **uint** and the other operand is of type sbyte, short, or **int**,
> both operands are converted to type **long**.
>
> ...